# Insert a fixed number of rows 2000 at a time in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert say 50,000 records into sql server database 2000 at a time. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the SELECT TOP clause: in MSSQL 2005 it was extended allowing you to use a variable to specify the number of records (older version allowed only a numeric constant)

You can try something like this:
(untested, because I have no access to a MSSQL2005 at the moment)

```
begin
declare @n int, @rows int

    select @rows = count(*) from sourcetable

    select @n=0

    while @n < @rows
    begin

        insert into desttable
        select top 2000 * 
        from sourcetable
        where id_sourcetable not in (select top (@n) id_sourcetable 
                    from sourcetable 
                    order by id_sourcetable)
        order by id_sourcetable

        select @n=@n+2000
    end
end
```

Comment: Yeah I did it similar to this. But instead of using NOT IN I used NOT EXISTS which is supposed to give better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for a test of some kind?

```
declare @index integer
set @index = 0
while @index < 50000
begin
   insert into table
   values (x,y,z)
   set @index = @index + 1
end
```

But I expect this is not what you mean.

If you mean the best way to do a bulk insert, use `BULK INSERT` or something like `bcp`

Comment: Not exactly. 50,000 rows but 2000 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

From an external data source [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) can be used to import the data.  The -b switch allows you to specify a batch size.

Answer (score 0):

declare @rows as int
set @rows = 1
while @rows >0

### begin

```
insert mytable (field1, field2, field3)
select   top 2000 pa.field1, pa.field2, pa.field3 
from table1 pa (nolock) 
left join mytable ta (nolock)on ta.field2 = pa.feild2
    and ta.field3 = pa.field3 and ta.field1 = pa.field1
where ta.field1 is null
order by pa.field1
```

set @rows = @@rowcount

end

This is code we are currently using in production in SQL Server 2000 with table and fieldnames changed.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL 2000, I'd probably lean on DTS to do this depending on where the data was located.  You can specifically tell DTS what to use for a batch commit size.  Otherwise, a modified version of the SQL 2005 batch solution would be good.  I don't think you can use TOP with a variable in SQL 2000.

Comment: I confirm, the use of a variable was added with SQL2005

Answer (score 0):

You can insert more than 1000 records using 'UNION ALL' in the INSERT statement. Below is the syntax. SQL Server will throw error if the records exceed 1000 records in the regular INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[dim_name] (Id, Name, Status)
SELECT 1,'ABC','Active'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'XYZ','Deactivated'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'DEF','Deactivated'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'LMN','Active'
;
```

Comment: Are you saying that one needs to write more than one thousand `UNION ALL SELECT ...` lines?

Comment: One workaround is to copy the data to excel and use excel CONCAT function to write the insert statement for one row and drag the function to other rows.